# what element to use for click event handler?

Tags: ajax, onclick

I deal with a question.

I want to load some content via ajax when user click on a text.

Does it matter to use `<a>` element or `<span>` element for this text while we can call `click()` for both of them?

Does it matter for search engines crawlers as I know from before they don't run js codes?

Comment: To answer your first question, i dont think you have to consider the element and associate a click event over it not for the text

Comment: simply yes it does matter, anything loaded with ajax will not be seen by searchengines or spiders , you can include this information as an hidden link in hte source code so that the engine does catch it

Comment: Depends on the use case and the target group. If accessibility is important you need to use `<a>` (or other _active_ elements) or `aria roles`. If SEO is important you need to make sure that the content is also reachable without js.

Comment: @brendan morrison i would not recommend you to use hidden links for search engines

Comment: what do you mean does it matter for "search engine crawlers"? Depends what you want searched on your page

Comment: @claustrofob how else would you make data accessible on a single html page site? ... more importantly for my own knowledge why?

Comment: @brendan morrison nowadays search engines are much more smarter then before. At least google bot renders the page and try to see it as real users see it. At best he will just ignore hidden links. Otherwise he can bun your site.

Comment: @brendanmorrison if you hide content from user and exclusive display it for search engines it either is not taken in account or worser you get a penalty (worse ranking or ban from index). In general there should be (except eyecandy) no difference for Searchengines (or disabled JS) and _normal_ page visitors.

Comment: @claustrofob thanks very good to know ... ill watch this question to figure out the correct way to do this then :) much appreciated +1 and to you t.niese

Comment: @brendan morrison usually i consider search engines as users without javascript support. Just turn off javascript and you should be able to navigate the site as the search bot. So either it supports javascript or not it will be able to reach the most of my content.